# python and multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have three functions in the python that each one puts an image (image path) as input and makes a simple image processing and creates a new image (image path) as output.

in the example below, one function depends on the other, ie:
the function of alg2 takes as input the image that generates the function of alg and the function of alg3 assign as input the image that generates the function of alg2 which depends on the function of alg1.

(I hope you do not mind basically)

because of their relatively high execution time (image processing is that) I would like to ask if I can
to parallelize them using python multiprocessing.
I have read about multiprocessing map and pool but I was pretty confused .

whenever I summarize I have three interdependent functions and I would like to run them together if done.
I would also like to know how I would perform these three functions in a contemporary way if they were not interdependent, ie each was autonomous.

```
def alg1(input_path_image,output_path_image):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    ###processing###)
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    print stop - start
    return output_path_image

def alg1(output_path_image,output_path_image1):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    ###processing###
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    print stop - start
    return output_path_image1

def alg3(output_path_image1,output_path_image2):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    ###processing###
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    print stop - start
    return output_path_image2

if __name__ == '__main__':
   alg1(input_path_image,output_path_image)
   alg2(output_path_image,output_path_image1)
   alg3(output_path_image1,output_path_image2)
```

Comment: If the execution of one function depends on the output of a previous function running to completion, you cannot run anything in parallel (what would that look like?). You may be able to use multiprocessing on individual functions to speed them up. The wording of your question is quite confusing and the content of your example functions doesn't give any indication of whether or not you could multiprocess them reasonably.

Comment: @roganjosh if my function is not need previous output then I cant ot run it parallel ?can you show my some example ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

I would split the list of images into smaller parts. Then I would make one function out of those three functions (by making the other 2 functions as private - just for the sake of simplicity). Then you can speed up the whole process by doing:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

image_list = this_is_your_huge_image_list
# create smaller image lists e.g. [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], ..]
chunked_lists = [image_list[x:x+100] for x in xrange(0, len(image_list), 100)]

for img_list in chunked_lists:
    p = Process(target=your_main_func, args=(img_list,))
    p.start()
    # without .join() here
```

Comment: on  `args=(img_list,))` maybe you mean `args=(chunked_lists,))` and on `image_list` you mean some like this `image_list='c:/path/to/image.png'` ?

Comment: @ChrisPapas no, `args` is what your main function gets as parameter which is a partial image list (from the huge image list) in this case. and `image_list` is something like: `['c:/path/1.png', 'c:/path/2.png', 'c:/path/3.png', '..', 'c:/path/N.png']`

Comment: for this task I have only one image

Comment: @ChrisPapas sorry, then I misunderstood your question

Comment: its ok maybe to divide in smaller image the main image ?then work,right ?or you have other idea ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're doing something CPU intensive, so you'll need to use the `multiprocessing.Process` object, rather than `threading.Thread`. Because of this, you can't return from `multiprocessing.Process`, and therefore will need to use a `multiprocessing.Manager`.

So this is an adaptation of your code which will work with `multiprocessing.Process`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def alg1(input_path_image,output_path_image, return_dict):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    ###processing###)
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    print stop - start
    return_dict['algo1'] = output_path_image

def alg2(output_path_image,output_path_image1, return_dict):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    ###processing###
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    print stop - start
    return_dict['algo2'] = output_path_image1

def alg3(output_path_image1,output_path_image2, return_dict):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    ###processing###
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    print stop - start
    return_dict['algo3'] = output_path_image2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()
    a1 = Process(target=alg1, args=(output_path_image,output_path_image, return_dict))
    a2 = Process(target=alg2, args=(output_path_image1,output_path_image1, return_dict))
    a3 = Process(target=alg3, args=(output_path_image2,output_path_image2, return_dict))
    jobs = [a1, a2, a3]
    for job in jobs:
        job.start()
    for job in jobs:
        job.join()
    a1_return = return_dict['algo1']
    a2_return = return_dict['algo2']
    a3_return = return_dict['algo3']
```

You'll need to modify this further to give your print statements a little more distinction. At the moment, they will only print a number, and you won't be able to distinguish between them.